# SQL bulk insert got overflow message

Tags: sql, bulkinsert

I'am trying to bulk insert and getting the error message:

"Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 1, column 1 (Socet)."

MODEL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbMakers](
    
    [Socet] [int] NULL,
    [Part] [int] NULL,
    [Mod] [int] NULL,
    [Tz] [int] NULL,
    [DateCreate] [int] NULL,
    [DateEdit] [int] NULL,  
    [DateTBD] [int] NULL,
    [Sol] [int] NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL
    
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

CODE:

```
 BULK INSERT dbo.dbMakers
    FROM 'G:\shr\AutoShmshdr.txt'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW=1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
    FORMATFILE = 'G:\shr\AutoShmshdr.fmt'
    )
```

FORMAT FILE:

```
12.0
9
1       SQLINT        0       1       ","      1     Socet      ""
2       SQLINT        0       2       ","      2     Part       ""
3       SQLINT        0       3       ","      3     Mod     ""
4       SQLINT        0       4       ","      4     Tz         ""
5       SQLINT        0       5       ","      5     DateCreate ""
6       SQLINT        0       6       ","      6     DateEdit   ""
7       SQLINT        0       7       ","      7     DateTBD    ""
8       SQLINT        0       8       ","      8     Sol   ""
9       SQLINT        0       9       "\r\n"   9     StatusID   ""
```

DATA:

```
122002751,40,1,74635269,20211227,20220104,20220105,1,2,                                                
122002751,40,6,39965538,20211227,20220104,20220105,1,2,                                               
122005333,84,1,65132250,20211123,20220104,20220105,2,2,                                                
122005333,84,6,52282779,20211123,20220104,20220105,2,2,
```

Comment: It's because your last field "StatusID" also has a comma after it so the input is expecting another column of data following that one.

Comment: I tried to remove it from the top three rows to see what happend, got the same error

Comment: Why do you think that only removing it from some of rows, not all of them, would solve the problem?

Comment: I did that at the end